# What do you do if an ec2 instance will not start?

Tags: windows-server-2003, amazon-ec2

It has just been siting on "Pending" for the last 5 minutes...

Comment: Could it be this; http://news.cnet.com/8301-30685_3-20056029-264.html

Comment: If it is EBS backed, it probably is related to that issue.  Also, try checking the server log available from the console.

Answer (score 1):

Contact Amazon support.

In this specific case, as @Chopper3 mentioned, they're experiencing an outage at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, I am hoping this will turn out to be the problem...